# Interpreting edi mscons files

Tags: r, parsing, edi

I have en EDI file in mscons format. I am trying to parse the file in R and save it as a csv file. However, I do not have any good explanation how to proceed. Anyone out there worked with these sort of files?

Example:

```
UNA:+.? '
UNB+UNOC:3+7080005046091:14:TIMER+102953452626:82:TIMER+140312:2152+XGATE019452198++++1'
UNH+1+MSCONS:D:96A:ZZ:E2NO6A'BGM+7+1488136+9+NA'
DTM+137:201403121751:203'DTM+163:201403030000:203'
DTM+164:201403092400:203'DTM+ZZZ:1:805'
NAD+FR+7080005046053::9+++++++NO'
NAD+DO+953452626:NO3:82+++++++NO'UNS+D'
NAD+XX'LOC+90+707057500071137750::9'
RFF+MG:97645'RFF+LI:22446237_17506927'
LIN+1++1491:::SM'MEA+AAZ++KWH'QTY+136:1'
DTM+324:201403030000201403030100:Z13'QTY+136:1'
DTM+324:201403030100201403030200:Z13'QTY+136:2'
DTM+324:201403030200201403030300:Z13'QTY+136:1'
DTM+324:201403030300201403030400:Z13'QTY+136:1'
DTM+324:201403030400201403030500:Z13'QTY+136:2'
DTM+324:201403030500201403030600:Z13'QTY+136:1'
DTM+324:201403030600201403030700:Z13'QTY+136:1'
DTM+324:201403092300201403092400:Z13'CNT+1:167181'
UNT+6832+1'UNZ+1+XGATE019452198'
```

Comment: Got a link to any info about the file format? Save us some googling.

Comment: this is edifact, messagetype MSCONS. There is specialized edifact software to read this and convert it to csv. Example of (open source) translator is http://bots.sourceforge.net. More information about edifact: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDIFACT

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a go. @Spacedman, I am sorry, I had very little information and primarily wanted so find out if anyone worked with edi mscons. I will update the post later when I figure out how the data is possible to parse.

Comment: @Alexander did you succeed in parsing MSCONS files with R? If yes, could you share the code? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Download this application to start:  [EDI Notepad](http://liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad)

Open your EDIFACT file in this tool.  This will help you with context.  What each segment / element is.  It should also help give you context related to qualifiers and envelopes in the documents.  You should find the source of the document and get an implementation guide, which will also explain their specific usage.

Once you apply context and understand what the elements are, parsing becomes easy.  You can write your own parser, use an open source product like BOTS (mentioned in the comments above, or purchase commercial translation software (hundreds available).

Answer (score 2):

The elements within the MSCONS file are well documented. See here: http://www.edi-energy.de - the latest description (in German) is available here: http://www.edi-energy.de/files2/MSCONS_2_2b_Fehlerkorrektur_2014_02_27.pdf